# Как настроить web.config в WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

помогите настроить web.config при переходе на http://localhost:1885/Service1.svc выдает исключение:System.InvalidOperationException: Чтобы запрос в операции EchoWithPut был потоком, операция должна иметь один параметр с типом Stream.
Вот этот метод

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
        UriTemplate = "/order/{ID}"
        , RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
        )]
    string EchoWithPut(string ID, Stream stream);
```

а вот сам метод

```
 public string EchoWithPut(string ID, Stream stream)
    {
        string json = "";
        string application_name = "", application_guid = "", IP = "", session_guin = "";
        string result_message = "";
        int result = 0;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);...
```

и web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
   </system.serviceModel>
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` - как это со стримом-то сочетается?

Comment: они не нужны? я прост впервые с wcf работаю

Comment: Сначала я написал это на консольном приложении(просто добавил службу wcf) и там все работало,

Answer (score 0):

> Операция должна иметь один параметр с типом Stream

У вас два параметра, один с типом string, второй с типом Stream. Уберите первый параметр из определения метода, и ошибка пропадет.

Comment: Спасибо, но я решил отойти от stream и получать json и вот так `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString()`